# Difference between $\limsup_{z\to a}\lvert f(z)\rvert$ and $\limsup \lvert f(z_n)\rvert$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

In case I miss something, I just copy exactly from the book.

There is a version of Maximum Modulus Theorem in the book says:

> Let $G$ be a region in $\Bbb{C}$ and $f$ an analytic on $G$. Suppose there is a constant $M$ such that $\limsup_{z\to a}\lvert f(z)\rvert \leq M$ for all $a$ in $\partial_\infty G$. Then $\lvert f(z)\rvert \leq M$ for all $z$ in $G$.

Here $\partial_\infty G$ means the extended bound.

And the statement in a question is like this:

> ... whenever $z$ is on $\partial_\infty G$ and $\{z_n\}$ is a sequence in $G$ with $z=\lim z_n$ we have $\limsup \lvert f(z_n)\rvert \leq M$. Show that $\lvert f(z) \rvert \leq M$, for each $z$ in $G$.

I don't know what differences do they have. The two conditions seems same to me. But it turns out that we have to show $$\limsup f(z_n) \leq M \Rightarrow \limsup_{z\to a} f(z) \leq M$$

then we reduce this case to the Theorem.

Aren't they talking about the same thing? When talking about limit I think we are talking about sequence, not some strange index set that is uncountable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $\limsup_{n\to\infty} f(z_n)$ considers only values of $f$ for the values of $z$ taken by the sequence $z_n$ while $\limsup_{z\to a} f(z)$ considers **all** values of $z$ in neighborhoods of $a$.

Take for example $f=(1-\chi_\mathbb Q)$ that is $0$ for rational numbers and $1$ otherwise. And let $z_n = 1/n$. Then $f(z_n) = 0$ (since $1/n$ is rational) so $\limsup f(z_n)=0$ however $\limsup_{z\to0} f(z) = 1$ since there exists non-rational numbers arbitrarily near $0$ (and for those $f$ is $1$).

Of course this function is not very analytical, but it at least show the difference...

Comment: So, naively speaking, for $z_n$ it's like going through some "paths", while $z \to a$ is talking about neighborhood, and if Cauchy-Riemann doesn't hold we will have some trouble?

Comment: @MonkeyKing Yes. Kind of, but $z_n$ also means that it's going with discrete steps too.